# AirDroid - How it works

Tags: android

I have been searching on the internet, but I didn't find what I want, so I'd like do know if you guys know how to do this.

There's an app named AirDroid, and I think you know it, but for those who don't, it enables a communication between your device and a browser. So you can control your smartphone through the internet, if both are connected at the same Wi-fi.

Do you guys know what I have to study to do it? Android SDK has some class that enables it?

Answer (score 4):

> Android SDK has some class that enables it?

Not specifically.

> Do you guys know what I have to study to do it?

I am going to assume that "do it" means "write my own implementation of the same thing".

Since it is a Web app, you will need to learn how to write Web apps, using some lightweight framework that is suitable for running on an embedded device.